# Magento product resize image issue

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

my server getting too slow due magento's resize image. i am using following code for display image

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(250,250)
```

This is load actual image (if i upload havy image like 2mb,3mb ) if i am not using resize function but if i use this function then its always resize it to 250x250 that makes server extra work of resizing image which can be done once at uploading image
i just want to avoid this resize process so every time image will not resize it should be resized when we uploading in magento when create a product. please give me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just skip the resizing. Everything is done in `__toString()` so if you remove the resize() there is no resizing and the file is only copied to the cache.

*EDIT*
It is important that you have the right small image uploaded in the backend. You can upload multiple images. And set three (in standard installation image, small_image and thumbnail) in the backend. These images can be access via

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'IMAGE_TYPE')
```

So if you upload a 250x250px image, mark it as thumbnail then you can remove the resize and everything works fine.

What you can do - but don't ask me how - is to put the resized images into the cache. But there are a lot of problems, after inserting them, e.g. flush the image cache -> all images are deleted

Comment: i have tried it without resize then its showing whole large image which is about to 5 mb large image

Comment: is this possible to solve this problem means it find image in cache if not exists in cache then resize it

Comment: yes sure please re edit my question if you think this need more improvement

Comment: did you means if use `echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(250,250)` this code this it will generate resized image and after resize always use image from cache until i refresh cache from admin

am i right ?

Comment: I'm not sure wether I understand you correct. The images are only resized one time, after that, thay are loaded from the disk until you click the "Flush Catalog Images Cache" button in `System > Cache Management` and delete all of them, then they are recreated (only once)